# Can I use interactive buttons in InDesign to display "answer"?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, formatting, interaction, interactive

Our job ticketing system at work is super inefficient for what we do, so I'm trying to make a job ticket that allows us to check a few boxes and copy/paste any relevant details. I used check boxes for common materials, but that still leaves a bunch of clutter on print (all the other unchecked boxes still on the page).

I'd like to check a box, and then on print have all the other boxes go invisible, but have the one I checked display itself larger. See attached images. Example 1 is the current layout, and I'd like to see example 2 on print. Any ideas? Is there a better way? (I haven't used InDesign in ~6 years... sort of re-learning it)

Also, would there be a way to have them display sequentially if I chose more than one substrate?

Example 1:

[image: Example 1]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: This sounds like a project for HTML, which was made for this kind of interaction.

Comment: Yes, I was about to say that here, PDF is not an app.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys. I know the format isn't an app, but I was wondering the limits of the apps that create and display interactive PDFs. Thanks again!